# Will the following cached item expire after 15 minutes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

```
_cache.Insert(cacheKey, userList, null,
 Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
 new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0),
 CacheItemPriority.High, null);
```

My code above doesn't seem to be expiring the cache after 3 minutes, the userList object pulls data from the database that was updated, but the cache doesn't expire it after 15 minutes.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are explicitly setting the cache to never expire by using `Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration`. You want to use [`Cache.NoSlidingExpiration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.noslidingexpiration.aspx) instead:

> When used, this field sets the `slidingExpiration` parameter to the
>   `TimeSpan.Zero` field, which has a constant value of zero. The cached
>   item expires in accordance with the `absoluteExpiration` parameter
>   associated with the `Insert` or `Add` method call.

Comment: when calling insert, I find it confusing b/c the signature of the method call want you to insert BOTH the absolute and sliding times.  Isn't it one or the other?

Comment: I think it might be relevant to add that a page's cache can affect a controls cache if the page's cache value is longer.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing 15 minutes to sliding expiration parameter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05kd8d77.aspx

The interval between the time the inserted object was last accessed and the time at which that object expires. If this value is the equivalent of 20 minutes, the object will expire and be removed from the cache 20 minutes after it was last accessed. If you are using sliding expiration, the absoluteExpiration parameter must be NoAbsoluteExpiration.

If your cached object is accessed more often than every 15 minutes it will never expire.

```
_cache.Insert(
        cacheKey, 
        userList, 
        null, 
        new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0),
        Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
        CacheItemPriority.High, 
        null);
```

now the item will expire in 15 minutes